# Let $n$ be the odd integer $\geq 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

1. Find number of pairs of $(x,y)$ for $x+2y=n$
2. Find number of pairs of $(x,y,z)$ for $x+y+2z=n$

My attempt
1. For $n$ defined as $x+2y$ and for $n$ to be odd number, it must consist of odd number and even number to produce odd number. So either $x$ is odd then $y$ is even, or vice versa. But since there is $2y$ which means both $(x,y)$ can be odd number both, but still cant be even number for both.
Manually, i can tell that (3,1) and (1,2) is the examples of the pairs for $(x,y)$ but how to find the number of pairs of all?

2. If i can manage to solve 1. I think i probably can solve 2.

EDIT

1. (n-1)/2 is the answer somehow.

The $(x,y)$ is a positive integer

2. (n-1)(n-3)/4 is the answer

$(x,y,z)$ are positive integer

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions without other constraints.

Comment: I edited it the quest

Comment: When in doubt, solving a simpler problem might help unlock the right thinking. In 1, if it had instead been $x+y=n$, do you know why the answer is $n-1$? If you know the reason for that (and the best solution has nothing to do with even or odd, it's simpler than that), then the solution for $x+2y=n$ is not far away.

Comment: Please take time to proofread your posts. For example, capitalise *I* and check your title for typos.